# JLabel in JFrame setText() issue

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I'm a novice coder, and while I was working on a project containing JFrame, JPanel and JLabel, I ran into some weird problem of JLabel showing up in two places, where I set it to be at and the top-left corner of the frame rather than where it's supposed to be.

Here's the basic outline of the code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;     // for key listener
import java.awt.*;         

import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends JFrame {



   JFrame Game;
   JLabel label;
   GamePanel panel;   // GamePanel class is the panel class that extends JPanel

   public Game(String title) {

      super(title);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setSize(420 + 110,420 + 220);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
      this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      this.setResizable(false);

      label = new JLabel("Score : " + score);
      label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
      label.setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

      panel = new GamePanel(..appropriate variables);

      this.add(panel);
      this.add(label);
      this.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,50)));

      panel.setFocusable(true);
      panel.addKeyListener(new KeyHandler());

   }

   // some variables..


   class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {

      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
      {
         int keycode = e.getKeyCode(); 

         switch(keycode) {

             //cases for arrow keys, which will update the variable that panel uses

         }

         //some other tasks for the game..

         panel.updateVariables(...appropriate variables to update);
         panel.repaint();
         label.setText("Score : " + score);

      }

   }

   public static void main(String [] args)  {

      Game me = new Game("GAME");        

      me.setVisible(true);


   }

}
```

So the summary of the problem is that whenever setText ACTUALLY UPDATES the label, the label seems to show up in two places: top left corner of the JFrame and where I assigned it to show up. Interestingly the "buggy" label on the top left corner also updates when the real one is updated.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's the layout of GamePanel.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel
{      

   // some variables..

   // setXxx methods for corresponding variables

   void drawCursor(int x, int y)
   {
      //draws thicker rectangle around the selected position
      //uses setStroke, setColor, and draw(Rectangle)
   }

   public void paintComponent( Graphics g )   
   {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;         

      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

         for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            switch(gameGrid[j][i]) {   // I have an array grid[][] that has information of which color goes into the specific position of the grid

               // each case will setColor the corresponding color and use g2.fill(new Rectangle(...));
               case 0:
                  g2.setColor(...);
                  g2.fill(new Rectangle(...));
                  break;
               // and so on

            }
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.draw(new Rectangle(50 + (j * 420/size), 50 + (i * 420/size), 420/size,420/size));         
         }    
      }
      drawCursor(x, y);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that adds your components (label, panel, etc.) to the frame?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Oops, forgot to copy it here. It is at the end of the constructor. My bad. I edited so it's there where it should be.

Comment: `GamePanel` is overriding `paint` or `paintComponent` but isn't calling `super.paintXxx`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm still quite new to java, so would you mind explaining what it means it's overriding `paintComponent` but not calling `super.paintXxx`?

Comment: Show us the `GamePanel`...What you are describing can be achieved by breaking the paint chain when performing custom painting

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added the `GamePanel` outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you are overriding `paintComponent` (in `GamePanel`) but are not call `super.paintComponent`...

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )   
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;   
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
```

`Graphics` is a shared resource and is used to paint the contents of all the components been updated during a given paint cycle, this means, that when you receive a reference to the `Graphics` context, it will still have the "stuff" that was painted on it before you.  One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to clear the context ready for painting

Call `super.paintComponent(g);` before you do any custom painting

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g )   
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;   
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
```

Check out [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for details about how painting in Swing works

Comment: So the point of `super.paintComponent(g)` is to clear out what was drawn before to draw new stuff?

Comment: @ColinJang That's one of it's jobs, but in the case of `JPanel`, that's pretty much all it does...